# My android app doesn't use gpu with nnapi running onnx model

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-learning, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm trying to run my onnx model with gpu by using nnapi in android environment. I'm trying with this code.

```
/*part of MainActivity.kt*/
/*=====================================================================*/

val modelID = R.raw.mobilenetv2_int8
val mobelbyteArray = resources.openRawResource(modelID).readBytes()

val ortEnv = OrtEnvironment.getEnvironment()

val ortoption = SessionOptions()

ortoption.addNnapi()

var orisession = ortEnv?.createSession(mobelbyteArray,ortoption);

val height:Long = 224
val width:Long = 224
val batch_size = 1

val shape = longArrayOf(1, 3, height, width)
val env = OrtEnvironment.getEnvironment()

val imgData = FloatBuffer.allocate(height.toInt() * width.toInt() * batch_size * 3)

val inputName = orisession?.inputNames?.iterator()?.next()

env.use {
    val tensor = OnnxTensor.createTensor(env, imgData, shape)
    val startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
    tensor.use {
        val output = orisession?.run(Collections.singletonMap(inputName, tensor))

    }
}

/*=====================================================================*/
```

```
/*build.gradle*/
/*=====================================================================*/
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.onnxrunkt'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.onnxrunkt"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    /*
    aaptOptions{
        noCompress 'onnx'
    }

     */
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.microsoft.onnxruntime:onnxruntime-android:1.14.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
/*=====================================================================*/
```

But this code doesn't use gpu at all. My phone model is "Galaxy s10 5g" with Android 12. How can I use gpu with nnapi? All of onnx model layers support gpu.

I tried adding CPU_DISABLES option to "addnnapi" method. but it doesn't worked.